# Need help unclogging condensate drain for furnace

Tags: furnace, condensation

https://imgur.com/a/Ov8bRGq

Bryant furnace model: **912SC48060S17**

We have sever weather here in Portland, OR and my Bryant/Carrier furnace is blowing cold air with status code 31.

- Replaced filter
- Cleaned flame burner rod
- Rinsed Condensate Drain Trap. Mine looks something like this: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51Pbhu4rvTL._SY445_SX342_QL70_FMwebp_.jpg

It worked for 1 hour and then again showing 31 code, also I see there is some water leak. I see there is water in elbow pipe(added image)..Is that normal?

Which pipe is supposed to drain the water? The one going into the floor? or the elbow pipe?

Should I drain water out of that elbow pipe?

I am also thinking of running a wire into the pipe(the one that is going into floor) to see if there is ice formed somewhere along?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There should be a label somewhere, likely on the inside surface of the burner or blower compartment door, that indicates what the code means. Please check for that, and/or share the model number of the furnace so we can look for its manual.

Comment: @GregHill Added model number and status code image that is on the panel of the furnace.

Answer (score 0):

You have furnace flue and A/C condensate lines joined at a tee.  That's bad because a blocked drain can cause either machine to flood the other.  And you have everything glued together so it's unserviceable.  It obviously needs to be cleaned out now, but it should be done annually.  Also the A/C has been plumbed nicely with a trap but it looks like maybe the pipe after the trap slopes upwards. Might just be the photo.

You should install an air gap floor drain where the pipe goes into the floor.  You *should* put a second drip pan around that with a water-sensing emergency cutoff.  Run two independent pipes from the two sources in your picture, to drip into the new floor drain, never connecting to one another.  If the drain freezes or is blocked it will back up into the pan and shut off the system.

If the floor drain goes into the sanitary sewer, there needs to be another downstream trap.  If there isn't one and nowhere for you to install one, you can't put an air gap here.  That would be a whole new Question.

If the floor drain freezes you need to address that.  Don't just clear the ice.  It needs to be reliable.

This is not guaranteed to be the reason for your code tripping but you really ought to do this anyway, and it will be easier to diagnose the code after if it keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

Code 31 is for a problem with a pressure switch.

Your furnace is a high-efficiency condensing type. This means that normal water vapor from the exhaust gas condenses to liquid in the furnace heat exchanger and also in the plastic flue pipe. It also means that the furnace must be equipped with an inducer fan which pushes the exhaust gas out.

The furnace is equipped with one or more pressure switches so that it can verify the inducer is working and that the exhaust flue is not obstructed. Pressure switches do fail, but so do inducers. Also flues can become obstructed. You'll have to figure out which of these has occurred.

Make sure the drain flows freely so that condensate water does not back up in the system. Listen for any kind of water splashing or sloshing sounds. If the exhaust flue is reachable, hold a hand in front of it to check whether a reasonable amount of air blows out. It should be somewhat comparable to a cool hair dryer in temperature and volume. You also can check all the small rubber tubes inside the furnace to see that none of those, or the nipples they press onto, is obstructed or broken.

If there was a problem with the exhaust flow it might be an obstruction or failing inducer. If not that, and if no other problem is found, then try replacing the pressure switch(es).